# How Java HTTP Microservice and HTTPS Microservice should communicated?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices

I'm new to Microservice. I want to know, What are the ways to communicate between HTTP microservice and HTTPS microservice? What would be best approach for this scenario?

HTTP & HTTPS Microservice Communications.

Thanks!!

Comment: This is not really a focused question. Please provide what you have tried and any code examples.

Answer (score 1):

In general , it is little  frequency that post the question which is abstract concept  in  stackoverflow , google it would be  better .
and there is three way to do this ,for my personly experience

#### use https

You'll need to configure the HTTP microservice to trust the certificate presented by the HTTPS microservice. This can be done by importing the HTTPS microservice's certificate into the truststore of the HTTP microservice.

#### Proxy

You can set up a reverse proxy (e.g., Nginx, Apache HTTP Server) in front of both microservices.This simplifies the communication between the microservices as each microservice only needs to handle one type of protocol (either HTTP or HTTPS).

#### Gateway

Use an API Gateway (e.g., Spring Cloud Gateway, Netflix Zuul) to route requests between the HTTP and HTTPS microservices. The API Gateway can handle both HTTP and HTTPS communication and route requests accordingly based on their destination microservice. This approach adds a layer of abstraction and allows for more flexible routing and management of requests.